# Loading Xib on UIView causing all the other components inside UIViewController hide

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xib, nsbundle

**Informations :** 
I am trying to **swap** two `.xib` which will be inside `UIView` of my **StepsUIViewController** class. And  I set their file owner name as my **StepsUIViewController** because I want to do their procedures inside that view controller and that is the important thing at this topic.

> **Requirement :**
>
> My requirement is changing the two `xib` base on each situation. So,
>   since I set their file owner name as StepsUIViewController,
>   implementation of both `xib` will be done inside StepsUIViewController.

And I am going to present that StepsUIViewController modally. So there will be no `UINavigationBar` until I drag and drop from tools.

**Here is my view hierachy :**

[image]

**And here is my StepsUIViewController :**

[image]

So inside `Step1View`, I will change the two xib I created base on **push(UIButton)** action. Now here comes the problem. When I load those xib, UINavigationBar didn't appear as well as `push` button also disappear and instead that xib(UIView) cover the whole `StepsUIViewController`.

Here is my code :

```
import UIKit


class StepsViewController: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var step1View : UIView!

     override func loadView() {
          super.loadView()
          let someView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("StepsInfo", owner: self, options:nil)[0]
          step1View = someView as! UIView
     }
}
```

Here what I am facing :

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?** I am new to xib and all my life dropping UIComponents to `UIViewController` inside storyboard and I am thinking to change it and create view dynamically on single UIViewController. Any Help?

Comment: you need to remove `view` from view controller in storyboard and it'll load it's `view` automatically from xib named same as class.

Comment: I don't want to cause my navigationbar is up there.Is there any way that i can swap uiview with two xib?

Comment: sorry I didn't read you question. So why you don't call `super.loadView()`?

Comment: @IgorBidiniuc,I forgot and that's not solving my case

Comment: Make `Step1View` as container for step view that you want to load. Load `Step1View` from `.xib` and add it on container.

Comment: @IgorBidiniuc, you mean i have to add uicontainerview and add those xib inside it?

Comment: The problem that makes all to disappear is that view controller is owner of `.xib` file and when you're loading this `.xib` it is setting new properties from `.xib`, but step view is set in `.xib` as view controller's `view`. This makes view controller to replace it's `view`. As result `step1View` is view controller's `view`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131559/discussion-between-thiha-aung-and-igor-bidiniuc).

Comment: I wrote you in chat you should check.

Comment: I don't know if its work or not,I got your answer.But,I want to do more.like accessing IBOutlet from UIViewcontroller,actions,and load some dynamic data.If those are available?mind if you explain me with some example

Comment: Mean there are a lot of UI element in Xib and I want to do button actions,Setting UILabel text,Getting Segment control selected,etc from UIViewController.BTW,your answer worked.I just need a little example that's all.Answer with some screenshot would be really helpful.Thanks